# SQL Server local server

Tags: sql-server

I created an app on C# using Windows Forms and it's working fine. I'm connecting to SQL Server using Windows authentication:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= ATWiki; Integrated Security=True;");
```

I have two questions:

1. If I want to connect another PC to the same server (both PC on same network), do I have to change the connection setting to SQL Server authentication or will it work with Windows authentication? What should the login values be on the second PC?
2. if it doesn't work, how can I create a login for SQL Server authentication? I know the default login name is `sa` but I forgot what password was specified on installation. How can I create a new login on the first pc and make the second pc connect to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if you want to connect remote server you must change connection look this [site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)

You must make some changes on server for remote connection

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQL Server Network Configuration Enabled VIA, TCP/IP

If you want to connect specific user , you must create login in SQL Server and write your connection user and password.

- Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Expend Security tab and create New Login
- Change Login Type Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication (if you connect Network user you can choore Windows authentication )
- set password (if you choore SQL Server authentication)
- Set Server role under the Server Roles Tab (For Example sysAdmin) [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx)
- you can set the user which database to connect under User Mapping

Answer (score 1):

When you want to connect with other server the best will be when you use ex. this connectionString

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

Here is more info : http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Integrated Security wouldn't work. You can create a second sa-login for your server using the following query:

```
USE master

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT loginname from master.dbo.syslogins 
    WHERE name = 'YOUR_LOGIN_NAME'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [YOUR_LOGIN_NAME] WITH PASSWORD = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
END

USE master

ALTER LOGIN [YOUR_LOGIN_NAME] ENABLE

EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'YOUR_LOGIN_NAME', 'sysadmin'

CHECKPOINT
```

How ever, be careful as I am sure you wont need a server admin just to access your database. Try to create a user for your database using the login you created. I think think this would work like that:

```
USE ATWiki
GO

-- not needed anymore
-- EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'YOUR_LOGIN_NAME', 'sysadmin'

sp_adduser 'YOUR_LOGIN_NAME', 'YOUR_NEW_USER_NAME', 'db_owner'; 
-- role is db_owner, apply whatever role suits your needs
```

As for the connection string. Find out the IP or Name of the maschine the sql server runs on. then your connectionstring would be sth. like:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Server=NAME_OF_THE_MASHINE_IN_YOUR_NETWORK;Database=ATWiki;User Id=YOUR_LOGIN_NAME;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD;");
```

Also note that mixed authentification must be enabled in order for logins to work!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to change the connection string. I think both of your questions boils down to that you have to take a look at SQL server security.

Weather you are using integrated security (windows authentication) or SQL server authentications you need to make sure that those users have access to your database.
I am guessing that you are using MS SQL Server with Management Studio:

1. Go to `SQL Server>Security>Logins` to create the users on the Microsoft SQL
   Server
2. Go to `Microsoft SQL Server>Databases>$database>Security` to
   grant access for the newly created users.

More info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669066(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming in C#. You can just create a new method for database initialization. Example:

```
public void programName()
{
      InitializeComponent(); 
      InitializeDatabase();
}`

 `private void InitializeDatabase()
  {
      string dbPath = @"yourdatabaseurlhere";
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" +                       dbPath + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = cn;
}`
```

I hope it works for you...